# Can I launch android app with default package name given by android studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, youtube-api

i started working on a project on android studio , initially i didn't know if I would go to launch the app so i let the package name be the same as given by android studio by default ( it was **com.example.abhishek.tv** ) . 
Now I'm done with the app and want to launch it but here I got stuck as I'm having my domain name as **abhishekint.16m.com** but i don't know to change the default package name given by android studio .

I have three problems here

1. I don't know to change the package name efficiently and **SAFELY**. I'm reluctant while changing the package name after reading some of the stackoverflow links as I was not clear with the answer and package name seems very sensible as it can ruin the whole project if not done properly .
2. My original domain name has numerics and I found after searching online that there is something abnormal with the numeric domain name .
3. One more thing , as I've this app which has some of the videos from youtube so in case if I choose to change the package name of my project then will I have to change the package name of the API_KEY that i got after fingerprinting while getting the youtube API .

Comment: Use version control if you think you'll break something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in your app-level `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz" // change here 
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

This will override package name that exist in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.xyz">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
```

**EDIT**

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) about naming packages in Java:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
>   special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name

This means you can't use a digit as the first character of a package (or a class, interface or variable name, for that matter).

`abhishekint.16m.com` not allowed but you can use `abhishekint.sixteenm.com`.

Comment: is this the only thing that i need to do as out there over internet  i saw a lot to be done for the purpose ? and what about the numeric domain name?

Comment: I think numeric are not allowed ? any reference/example having numeric package name ?

Comment: will changing application id override package name in every single place like in every java file , xml file . ?

Comment: `applicationId "com.abc.xyz"` is different from package name that you have for  your `.java` file. so it's not change from all place where your `.java` and `.xml` are referenced but you can leave that with old package name